# ROS indigo installation error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am trying to install ROS indigo but when i am trying to set up my keys

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
```

its showing the following error in terminal window

```
  gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
 gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214911/ros-indigo-installation-error/) by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a transient error. Please try again after some time.

Also, see [ROS indigo key server down](http://answers.ros.org/question/212254/ros-indigo-key-server-down/) for an alternative in case you don't want to wait for it to come back up.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-07-30**:
can i use the  command below instead of the steps in the offical site??

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oroca/oroca-ros-pkg/master/ros_indigo_install.sh && sudo sh./ros_indigo_install.sh
```

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-07-30**:
somneone told me this install ros in one go

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-30**:
Up to you. ROS installation is really only a few lines anyway. Just make sure the file does what you expect it to.

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-08-03**:
hi ni ahve installed ros and  setup my workspace but whenever i am opening the terminal this is showing again and again

bash: source~/Desktop/kinectrobot/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
universe@universe-HP-202-G2-MT:~$

after  type the clear command its not there

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-03**:
I cannot find that in the script you linked, so it's probably something that you did. Please open a new question for this unrelated issue.